# Class "Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry" sis not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, gedmo-loggable

I try to use Gedmo Loggable extensions for Doctrine2 but I got an error and I didn't understand why.

I got the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class
>   "Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry" sub class of
>   "Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry" is not a
>   valid entity or mapped super class. in
>   C:\Projects\easyprod\librairies\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php
>   on line 340

when I run

```
$article = new \classeDoctrine\Article;
$article->setTitle('my title');
$oGestionnaireEntites->persist($article);
$oGestionnaireEntites->flush();

$article = $oGestionnaireEntites->find('\classeDoctrine\Article', 1);
$article->setTitle('my new title');
$oGestionnaireEntites->persist($article);
$oGestionnaireEntites->flush();

//$repo = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry');

$repo = $oGestionnaireEntites->getRepository('Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry'); // we use default log entry class
$article = $oGestionnaireEntites->find('classeDoctrine\Article', 1);
$logs = $repo->getLogEntries($article);

// lets revert to first version
$repo->revert($article, 1);
// notice article is not persisted yet, you need to persist and flush it
echo $article->getTitle(); // prints "my title"
$oGestionnaireEntites->persist($article);
$oGestionnaireEntites->flush();
```

configuration file-

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
    Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Autoloader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

//charge l'autoload voir composer.json
require_once ROOT . "/librairies/autoload.php";

// First of all autoloading of vendors
$loader = require ROOT . "/librairies/autoload.php";
// gedmo extensions
$loader->add('Gedmo', ROOT . "/librairies/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib");

$tCheminEntites = array(
    ROOT . '/class/doctrine',
    ROOT . '/class/doctrine/entite/grilleResultat',
    ROOT . '/class/doctrine/entite/analyse',
    ROOT . '/class/doctrine/entite/matrice',
    ROOT . '/class/doctrine/entite/test',
);

foreach ($tCheminEntites as $sCheminEntite) {
    // autoloader for Entity namespace
    $loader->add('classeDoctrine', $sCheminEntite);
}



//Paramètre de la base de données
$tBddParametres = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'easyprod',
    'charset' => 'UTF8'
);



Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(
        ROOT . '/librairies/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php'
);


$bModeDeveloppement = true;
// globally used cache driver, in production use APC or memcached
$cache = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
// standard annotation reader
$annotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader();
$annotationReader->addNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping');
$cachedAnnotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
        $annotationReader, // use reader
        $cache // and a cache driver
);
// create a driver chain for metadata reading
$driverChain = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain();
// load superclass metadata mapping only, into driver chain
// also registers Gedmo annotations.NOTE: you can personalize it
Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM(
        $driverChain, // our metadata driver chain, to hook into
        $cachedAnnotationReader // our cached annotation reader
);

// now we want to register our application entities,
// for that we need another metadata driver used for Entity namespace
$annotationDriver = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver(
        $cachedAnnotationReader, // our cached annotation reader
        $tCheminEntites// paths to look in
);



// NOTE: driver for application Entity can be different, Yaml, Xml or whatever
// register annotation driver for our application Entity namespace
$driverChain->addDriver($annotationDriver, 'classeDoctrine');



//$oDefaultAnnotationDriver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($tCheminEntites);
// NOTE: driver for application Entity can be different, Yaml, Xml or whatever
// register annotation driver for our application Entity fully qualified namespace
//$driverChain->addDriver($oDefaultAnnotationDriver, 'classeDoctrine');
// general ORM configuration
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
$config->setProxyDir(sys_get_temp_dir());
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxy');
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false); // this can be based on production config.
// register metadata driver
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverChain);
// use our already initialized cache driver
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);






// create event manager and hook preferred extension listeners
$evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();
// gedmo extension listeners, remove which are not used
// loggable, not used in example
$loggableListener = new Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener;
$loggableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
$evm->addEventSubscriber($loggableListener);


//Paramètre de la base de données
$tBddParametres = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'easyprod',
    'charset' => 'UTF8'
);

$oGestionnaireEntites = EntityManager::create($tBddParametres, $config, $evm);

$oGestionnaireEntites->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('HydratorValeurSansNomColonne', 'boiteAOutils\HydratorValeurSansNomColonne');
```

Comment: Yikes.  Did you copy that config code from someplace?  Looks awfully messy.  You seem to be loading autoload.php twice with a require_once?  Unless you have similar code I'd suggest using the composer autoload functionality and maybe look in the gedmo docs for an example.  You will need to specify a path to your Log entity for mapping but I honest can't follow your logic.

Comment: Yes,
There is a double inclusion, I tried to copy/paste the configuration file from Gedmo doctrine extensions.
I already use composer ;)

Comment: This is the Atlantic18 stuff right?  I'm just a bit suspicious because you have all that ROOT stuff and librarias instead of vendor.  I would make a clean project, get the example running and then try to add one of your entities.